# Protect CDN to only server up files if user is Auth - IIS 7

Tags: c#, iis-7, security, cdn

We found an issue with our in-house CDN solution.

An Auth user adds photo's or docs to their project.
We upload the files to local driver on the server different from the website application.

```
Example: mysite.com [ d:\websites\mysite.com\]  running web-app
Example: cdn.mysite.com [ e:\cdn\mysite.com\assests\]  storage area
```

If a Auth user uploads a an image ... then right-clicks on it, the exposed URL 
is:

```
http://cdn.mysite.com/assests/30b3bddc-fe1b-4fef-92c0-576bb6e5b487
/p/347e4ec6-3e36-4ac3-932a-a686d3cffd51/t/347e4ec6-3e36-4ac3-932a-a686d3cffd
51.jpg
```

We are using GUID for the Project Folder / User Folder / ImageName.jpg

However, if you copy/paste and send this URL to a friend (Not Auth user), you can access the image/file/etc ...

How can we protect the CDN to only server up files if user is Auth?

Windows 2008 Server
IIS 7
ASP.NET 4
C# Web app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom HTTP Module that handles all incoming requests to the cdn site. In the handler you can check if they are authenticated or not

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly referencing the files you could force it to go through a generic http handler.  The handler should check the login status of the request and if it isn't logged in don't server any content.